# Twitter Authentication through Android's AccountManager classes

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, accountmanager

I am working on a twitter based app and am trying to incorporate Android's built-in Account support for Twitter. The following code works to popup the confirmation dialog for my app to access twitter but I am unsure of what to pass in as the authenticationType. Any help would be appreciated. I've googled all over the place and can't seem to find the correct answer. It goes in place of "oauth" below.

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accts = am.getAccountsByType(TWITTER_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
if(accts.length > 0) {
    Account acct = accts[0];
    am.getAuthToken(acct, "oauth"/*what goes here*/, null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
        try {
                     Bundle b = arg0.getResult();  
                     Log.e("TrendDroid", "THIS AUTHTOKEN: " + b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));  
                } catch (Exception e) {  
                     Log.e("TrendDroid", "EXCEPTION@AUTHTOKEN");  
                }  
    }}, null);
}
```

Comment: Excellent question :-) Can you provide the value of TWITTER_ACCOUNT_TYPE so that the answer is complete?

Comment: com.twitter.android.auth.login

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want OAuth you should use those ones :

- **com.twitter.android.oauth.token**
- **com.twitter.android.oauth.token.secret**

If you want the user's password then you can write your own authenticator. The official Twitter application does not store the password. The password is used only once to get those two tokens.

Comment: Does Facebook has this type of oauth on Android? In our company they are using a FbDialog with in our app. But how can user trust that it is a facebook dialog and not some stupid pishing?

Comment: Are this tokens valid to authenticate against the api and a application? I am trying to use it and, I am receiving an 401 error. When I try to invalidate the token trying to receive another one it does not work. Any idea/clue? Thanks

Comment: @PedroFraca, in my testing Android's AccountManager Twitter tokens only work in combination with Twitter's official Consumer Key & Secret (which are out there...). Without using Twitter's credentials you have to use a WebView authorization flow, and have the user enter the resulting pin in your app. I have a fully open-source solution here: https://github.com/OpenWatch/OpenWatch-Android/blob/twitter/OpenWatch/src/org/ale/openwatch/twitter/TwitterUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

from [AccountManager docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html):

> Some authenticators have auth token types, whose value is
>   authenticator-dependent. Some services
>   use different token types to access
>   different functionality -- for
>   example, Google uses different auth
>   tokens to access Gmail and Google
>   Calendar for the same account.

I think, it is not very important. You should really ask the developer of twitter authenticator. Or write your own.