# Android Account Manager - obtaining token secret

Tags: android, oauth, gmail-imap

From my understanding to access the gmail API using XOAUTH authentication it is required you have a [token and token secret](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_protocol) if you wish to use the 3-legged-authentication.

I can obtain the token from the account manager `AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN` but I am unsure how to obtain the token secret.

```
accountManager.getAuthToken(account,  "oauth2:https://mail.google.com/", null, MainActivity.this,
new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

    @Override
    public void run(final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
        try {

            final String token = future.getResult().getString(
                    AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}, null);
```

Is it possible to obtain the token secret from the account manager or would I have to launch  the browser to obtain this information?

Comment: [Previous question][1] which might answer your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868770/twitter-authentication-through-androids-accountmanager-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the research that I have concluded this is not possible.

However a possible solution to overcome this problem would to be to use the [Signpost oAuth](https://github.com/kaeppler/signpost) library which enables request tokens to be returned from the browser.